# Extracting rows from a matrix conditional on another variable

Tags: r, matrix

How do I extract the rows of `m` where `a` is even? For example,

```
m = matrix(1:24, 6)
a = c(3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but I think I know what you mean. For your data:

```
m = matrix(1:24, 6)
a = c(3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5)
```

You could mean that you want to select all the rows in `m` where `a` is even. So, in this case, you would want the *second* and *fifth* rows of `m`, because only the second and fifth element of `a` is even. In this case, this would work:

```
 m[a %% 2 ==0,]
```

I think, however, you meant that you wanted to find the numbers in `a` that were even, (in this case 2 and 4) and then select those rows of `m`. In that case, you would use:

```
m[a[a %% 2 ==0],]
```

So that would select first the *fourth*, and then the *second* row of m. Remember, however, that if you have any even number in there twice, it will select the row twice.

If you wanted to select the rows in order (row 2 and then row 4) you would do:

```
m[sort(a[a %% 2 ==0]),]
```

Comment: When I try this m[a %% 2 ==0,] I get this matrix. The second row is uneven. 
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    8   14   20
[2,]    5   11   17   23
But thanks anyway for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
m[which(a %% 2 != 0), ]
```

Comment: Hello,thank you for helping me. m[a %% 2 ==0,]should be te correct but when I tried it in R I get this matrix [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    8   14   20
[2,]    5   11   17   23

Comment: Sorry incorrect matrix: I mean when I try m[a %% 2 ==0,]I get this matrix: 
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    8   14   20
[2,]    5   11   17   23
So, row 2 are uneven values?

Comment: I think @nograpes answer is correct. If you want extract the rows from m in which all values are even, regardless of the values ​​of a, you can try: m[unique(which(m %% 2==0, arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]), ]